# React-Bootstrap not working on components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I just began a new react app and wanted to implement react-bootstrap (did so by running npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap)
The Column, Row and Button tags are not working, and the react-bootstrap folder exists in the node-modules folder.

```
import React from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import {Button, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          <Col>
          hi
          </Col>
          <Col>
          bye
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Button variant='primary'>hi</Button>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Just in case it is relevant, I am working on windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import bootstrap.

Add the following to import bootstrap. Depending on your folder structure the relative path may be different.

```
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Then bootstrap will be available to your App component and all it's child components.

```
import React from "react";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import { Button, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          <Col>hi</Col>
          <Col>bye</Col>
        </Row>
        <Button variant="primary">hi</Button>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Another option is to import bootstrap in your index.js and it will be available to all your components.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot